# Azure finding resource-group quota

Tags: azure, azure-cli

with `az container create --resource-group <my-resource-group> .......`
I get an error if the ContainerGroupQuotaReached has been reached:

```bash
(ContainerGroupQuotaReached) Resource type 'Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups' container group quota 'StandardCores' exceeded in region 'norwayeast'. Limit: '10', Usage: '10' Requested: '1'.
```

I found that `az quota ...` should help, but:

```bash
az quota show --resource-name ContainerGroupQuotaReached \
--scope /subscriptions/<my account id>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/locations/norwayeast

(AuthorizationFailed) The client '<my client id>' with object id '<client object id>' does \
not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Quota/quotas/read' over scope \
/subscriptions/<my account id>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/locations/norwayeast/providers/Microsoft.Quota/quotas/ContainerGroupQuotaReached'
```

I have a limited account that can only push and deploy containers to a resource-group

Is there a way I can see this quota up front?

Comment: I don't think so. You need to ask permission. Your IT team can create a custom role to allow you to do this.
You can also ask your IT team to create an alert on your quota. This will enable you (and them) to plan ahead.

Answer (score 1):

```bash
(AuthorizationFailed) The client '<my client id>' with object id '<client object id>' does \
not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Quota/quotas/read' over scope \
/subscriptions/<my account id>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/locations/norwayeast/providers/Microsoft.Quota/quotas/ContainerGroupQuotaReached'
```

As per the error, you don't have access to check the quota usage. To check the **Usage + quotas** on `subscription` , you may need at least **Quota Request Operator**.

```bash
> Is there a way I can see this quota up front?
```

Alternatively, you can check the **StandardCores** quota limit per `region` **norwayeast** per `subscription` by navigating to below step.

Go to **Portal > Subscription > Usage + quotas > Provider:  Azure Container Instanced > Region : norwayeast > Standard Cores**

[image]

**References:**

[Update the quota limit for a specific resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/quota?view=azure-cli-latest#az-quota-update)

Check the quota usage using  [REST API](https://zimmergren.net/get-container-instances-usage-in-azure-subscription/)